# How does flushing promises work in relation to the Node.js event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given this snippet:

```js
function flushPromises() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setImmediate(resolve);
    });
  }

let a;
let b;

Promise.resolve().then(function defineA () {
    a = 1;
}).then(function defineB () {
    b = 2;
})

flushPromises().then(function logAB () {
    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)
})
```

I seem to have some trouble understanding the event loop concerning the role of `setImmediate` here.  According to this article: https://blog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa, promises are added into a single microtask queue that is checked after every event loop phase.

If I remove the `setImmediate` from `flushPromises`, I get the output:

```js
function flushPromises() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve()
    })
}
```

```
1
undefined
```

I believe this is because the microtask queue looks like this, since `defineB` runs after the `defineA` has ran:

```
[defineA, logAB, defineB]
```

so by the time `logAB` is run, `defineB` did not run yet, which makes sense according to the queue.

When I add back `setImmediate`:

```js
function flushPromises() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setImmediate(resolve)
    })
}
```

```
1
2
```

Is this because by the time `setImmediate` runs, it goes through the event loop again and any promise callbacks remaining in the microtasks queue would be executed after any of the phases before it reaches the `poll` (https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) phase?

```
[defineA]
[defineA, defineB]
[defineB]
[]
[logAB]
```

I would greatly appreciate some insight as to exactly what `setImmediate` does here. Thanks in advance.

(To be more specific, I'm talking about Node.js v11+

Comment: `setImmediate` is a *non-standard feature*. It can do *literally anything* dependent on implementation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate

Comment: Not sure why this is called `flushPromises`, it not flushing anything, it's delaying the resolve until next tick, so that's why you get 1,2 using it.  As without the promises can be executing `async`, so getting `1, undefined` makes sense too.

Comment: I've clarified the question to target Node.js v11+ specifically. The explanation that it delays until the next tick doesn't quite make sense to me given the difference between `setImmediate` and `process.nextTick` - if I change `setImmediate` to `process.nextTick`, it will also log `1,undefined` since (according to the article I posted), tick callbacks are run before microtasks after each event loop phase (as part of the Node.js implementation)